# I added a row using JS, but it gets immediately deleted after a few seconds/miliseconds, the console log also shows no error

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, tr

So, I made two tables, one table has a form included in it, you will type whatever you want in that form, and then it will show in the other table.

```
          <table>
                <head>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Product Price</th>
                        <th>Product Quantity</th>
                        <th>Product Barcode</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <form id="input">
                            <td><input class="userinput" id="productname" type="text" placeholder="Product Name"></td> 
                            <td><input class="userinput" id="productprice" type="text" placeholder="Product Price"></td>
                            <td><input class="userinput" id="productquantity" type="number" placeholder="Product Quantity"></td>
                            <td><input class="userinput" id="productcode" type="number" placeholder="Product Barcode"></td>
                            <td><button>Add Products</button></td>
                        </form>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Users will enter data in this table and the data will show up in table 2 that is:

```
<table id="products">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Product Price</th>
                        <th>Product Quantity</th>
                        <th>Product Barcode</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="plist">
                    <tr>
                        <td> product name 1</td>
                        <td>product price 1</td>
                        <td>product quantity 1</td>
                        <td>product bardcode 1</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

The JS Code used here is:

```
<script>
    const formel = document.querySelector('#input');
    const tableel=document.querySelector('#plist');
    function addRow(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    const pname = document.getElementById('productname').value;
    const pprice = document.getElementById('productprice').value;
    const pquan = document.getElementById('productquantity').value;
    const pcode = document.getElementById('productcode').value;
    tableel.innerHTML+= `
    <tr>
        <td>${pname}</td>
        <td>${pprice}</td>
        <td>${pquan}</td>
        <td>${pcode}</td>
    </tr>
    `;
}   
formel.addEventListener("submit", addRow)
</script>
```

The item gets added for a few seconds/millions, immediately gets deleted. I tried checking the console, it shows no error.

I am new to javascript, honestly, I got js code by watching various YouTube videos, but I can't understand why will the table row get immediately deleted after being added.

If anybody helps it will really be helpful, thank you in adavance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since preventDefault is a method, you need to change `e.preventDefault` to `e.preventDefault();`.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't call e.preventDefault, click on the *Add Products* button makes a request and sends form's data to server, then it shows this request's response (which is nothing) as a result after some miliseconds you can see just an empty page. To solve the problem you need to change e.preventDefault to e.preventDefault() and this change prevents submiting the form.

Comment: Thank you so much, such a small thing feels like a stupid question to ask. Thank you for helping. I overlooked the brackets.